# CSRF Verification Failed - Django

Tags: python, django, web

I don't know how to get around this CSRF failure. I've included the {% csrf_token %} that I keep reading about but it still gives me this error. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Log in</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        body{
        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ state }}
        <form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% if next %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            {% endif %}
            username:
            <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
            password:
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've included all the proper features for this but if you need to see any more code let me know...I think this is all that applies though...

EDIT: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import *

def login_user(request):
  state = "Please log in below..."
  username = password = ''
  if request.POST:
      username = request.POST.get('username')
      password = request.POST.get('password')

      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
          if user.is_active:
              login(request, user)
              state = "You're successfully logged in!"
          else:
              state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
      else:
          state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

  return render_to_response('auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

Comment: What is "this error"?  Can you post a full traceback of the error you're seeing?  Can you post the view code?  It'll help us better diagnose your issue.

Comment: Are you including just the token without HTML markup?

Comment: ^^^ It should be included that way. OP: have you inspected the HTML to see if the `{% csrf_token %}` tag actually generates the hidden input element? Otherwise review the points 1. to 3. here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: The error is just what's stated, it is a CSRF verification failure. From what i can see, there is no traceback log. I've added the view.py file if it help diagnose the issue.

Comment: please post your settings codes

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the token to the template context, try something like this, and read up on the documentation/tutorial linked to in the comments to your question.

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def login_user(request):
    ...your code...
    ctx = {'state':state, 'username': username}
    ctx.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('auth.html',ctx)
```

Comment: Or just use `render` instead of `render_to_response`.

Answer (score 0):

In your view,return a `context_instance` to the template as follows

```
from django.template import RequestContext
def login_user(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('auth.html',{'state':state, 'username':
     username},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```